# What race crown for a 3T Exloro fork?

Tags: bearings, 3t, headtube

More than half a year ago, I bought a 3T Exploro Team frameset. To my big surprise, when building the bike, the fork's race crown is missing.

The brand of the head tube cups is Cane Creek.

Asking since my Google-Fu doesn't cut it this time...

Comment: Can you post a photo of crown race area? Any chance the CR is integrated?

Comment: Thanks for asking this question, I was curious as well.  Also, wanted to add a follow up question for you. What to do with those red strips and foam tubing that came with the Exploro kit?

Answer (score 1):

When I looked at their site, 3T didn't call out numbers for the fork, but it would appear the frameset uses one of the more common contermporary setups, IS52 for the frame and therefore a crown race that Cane Creek describes as 52/40, the 40 being the OD classification of the crown race seat under SHIS nomenclature. Crown races like that are basically all the same and interchangeable, because they live in a world where they have to be stand-ins for forks that have integrated crown races, which are headset-brand-neutral. So if the above assumptions about your frameset are true, you're safe using whatever 52/40 crown race you can get your hands on, but the Cane Creek one that should match is their part number BAA0173A.

Comment: I was following this guide (step 7): https://www.instructables.com/3T-Exploro-Build-Up/

However, since I'm having the newer "flat-mount" frameset, it seems like the race crown is molded into the fork. Should I add grease? if so, what kind?

The fork in question: https://photos.app.goo.gl/d6kh9jZPPmjUYs1h9

Comment: @T0TTE looks like an integrated crown race. I don't add grease to mine, the bearing are sealed cartridges anyway.

Comment: @T0TTE Yes, that's an integrated crown race, you don't need a seperate one. Greasing or not is discretionary; sometimes integrated headset can have issues with creaking sooner or later that adding grease can mitigate, but it also attracts dirt. I usually take the bearing itself and put a very thin layer over the contact surfaces, half a of a pea-sized dot spread around.